# Simplifying an 'if' statement with bool()

Tags: python, boolean, refactoring, lint, pylint

I have some code that causes Pylint to complain:

> The if statement can be replaced with 'var = bool(test)' (simplifiable-if-statement)`

The code (with obfuscated variable names) is below.

```
A = True
B = 1
C = [1]
D = False
E = False

if A and B in C:
    D = True
else:
    E = True

print(D, E)
```

How can this be simplified so that Pylint does not throw any errors?

I don't quite understand how `bool()` can be used for this. I know it converts any value to a Boolean value, but I don't know how it can be applied here.

Comment: What do you expect `D` and `E` to be in the *other* case?

Comment: This is going to NameError when it tries to access E.

Comment: Sorry, yes you guys are right. @StephenRauch I have updated the code.

Comment: This *could* be true of you were assinging to the same variable inside the `if` and `else` blocks, which you aren't. Maybe pylint is simply messing up here

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That logic can be expressed as:

```
D = A and B in C
E = not D
```

Comment: Ah yes, that is quite clean.

Comment: I would argue that this creates the opportunity to introduce a bug when changing how `D`'s value is computed because that would implicitly change how `E`'s value is computed.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
D = bool(A and B in C)
E = not bool(A and B in C)
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would be something along those lines. I suppose a slight tweak would be to store the conditional in a variable, and then `D = cond; E = not cond`?

Answer (score 3):

I was initially a bit confused by the accepted answer and then realized my problem was not with the accepted answer itself (which is fully correct indeed) but with the specificity of the question. I needed a more generic / simple use case and so I will try to provide one, hoping it will be of help for someone.

The `simplifiable-if-statement` Pylint refactor basically happens when we use an *if-else* statement to assign a value to a boolean variable, which could have otherwise been assigned directly, without using the *if-else* statement at all.

A generic example could be:

```
if <condition>:
  variable = True
else:
  variable = False
```

which can (and should) be simplified as:

```
variable = <condition>
```

where `<condition>` is a boolean expression.

A concrete example:

```
if a > 5:
  b = True
else:
  b = False
```

should be rewritten as

```
b = a > 5
```

Getting back to the original question, in this case the condition is `A and B in C` and, as pointed out by other contributors, the redundant snippet:

```
D = False
E = False
if A and B in C:
    D = True
else:
    E = True
```

should be simplified as

```
D = A and B in C
E = not D
```